# Binding Javascript keypress events

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, client-side

I have a need to monitor the state of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, whether it is up or down. Its purpose is to notify the user that while the <kbd>shift</kbd> key is held down, the drag and drop operation they are about to perform is going to COPY the node(s), and not move them.

I have it working perfectly with the code below, however, if I hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and perform the drag and drop, the hook no longer exists; the screen no longer responds to the key press and remains in the "pressed" state.

I'm guessing there is either an order of operations issue or a missing piece. Javascript experts please advise.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><ASP:Literal id="treeLeft" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <asp:Label ID="lblCopyEnabled" runat="server" BackColor="Green" Text="Item will be Copied" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; display: none" />
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     document.onkeydown = KeyDownHandler;
     document.onkeyup = KeyUpHandler;

     var SHIFT = false;

     function KeyDownHandler(e) {
         var x = '';
         if (document.all) {
             var evnt = window.event;
             x = evnt.keyCode;
         }
         else {
             x = e.keyCode;
         }
         DetectKeys(x, true);
         ShowReport();
     }
     function KeyUpHandler(e) {
         var x = '';
         if (document.all) {
             var evnt = window.event;
             x = evnt.keyCode;
         }
         else {
             x = e.keyCode;
         }
         DetectKeys(x, false);
         ShowReport();
     }
     function DetectKeys(KeyCode, IsKeyDown) {
         if (KeyCode == '16') {
             SHIFT = IsKeyDown;
         }
         else {
             if (IsKeyDown)
                 CHAR_CODE = KeyCode;
             else
                 CHAR_CODE = -1;
         }
     }
     function ShowReport() {
         var copyLabel = document.getElementById("<%= lblCopyEnabled.ClientID %>");
         if (SHIFT) {
             copyLabel.style.display = "inline";
             ob_copyOnNodeDrop = true;
         }
         else {
             copyLabel.style.display = "none";
             ob_copyOnNodeDrop = false;
         }
         
     }
</script>

</form>
```

Comment: do you have any idea why this isn't working? suspected code sections that are failing?  `ex: is the keyUpHandler being called at some point?`  might give you an idea...

Comment: Where's the drag and drop part?  What code is involved with *that*?

Comment: Do you really want to copy when Shift is pressed? Usually, the system copies when Ctrl is pressed and moves when Shift is hold down. And you really should normalize the Event interface using `e = e || window.event`, don't check for `document.all` and assume it's IE that's running.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I forgot to mention that I removed the code entirely that performed the actual drag and drop and only left in the notification for copy or move. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code is failing, since you didn't include drag and drop code, but there's an easier way to do what you want. For any event fired by the browser, you can access shiftKey property, which is going to be true, if the shift key is pressed:

```
window.onmousemove = checkShift;

function checkShift(e)
{
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.shiftKey)
  {
    ....Copy....
  }
  else
  {
    ....Move....
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly, however, it only seems to work in FireFox. Any suggestions for making it work in IE7+ ? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the code to work in IE as well. shiftKey is crossBrowser, it's just a matter of wiring event correctly and using window.event vs. attribute.