# How to activate a popup menu in html when a certain key is pressed

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how can you make a popup appear when a certain key is pressed!. For example. While im on my website and i press the key "U" on my keyboard to upload a file and popup will appear. On mediafire.com theres one that works when you press the "u" key and the upload popup dialoge appear! can someone help me with that. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding javascript keypress events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250463/binding-javascript-keypress-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using javascript.

```
object.onkeydown=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

You can also use HTML5 instead. For more info see here: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/JS/html5_canvas_keyboard_keys.html

Comment: You could use keycode and char code. It's explained here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html
There are still some inconsistencies with different browser so you should use jQuery instead: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="Popup" style="display:none;">
    Upload form here
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function doKeyDown(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 85) {
            document.getElementById('Popup').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```